# Polymorphism in java classes

Tags: java, polymorphism

Given the next classes:

```
public class AA {     
    public int _x;   

    public AA() {     
        this(1);     
    }  

    public AA(int k) {     
         _x = k*10;     
    } 

    public int getX() {    
        return _x ;     
    }     
} 

public class BB extends AA {     
    public int _x; 

    public BB() {     
        this(2);     
    } 

    public BB(int k) {     
        super(k+1);
        _x = super.getX() + 1; 
    }      

    public int getX() {     
        return _x;     
    }    
}
```

If I perform the next operation:

```
a =new BB();
```

I think I should get the _x value of 31, but this is not what I am getting. In my understanding of polymorphism the _x value should come from the class AA, is that not the case?

Comment: How is `a` declared? What are you using to examine the value of `_x`?

Comment: The value of `_x` in `BB` will be `31` and on `AA` will be `30`. Is that not what you are getting?

Comment: _...but this is not what I am getting._ Why do you think that not providing what you are really getting makes your question more clear than telling us that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are not overridden, only hidden.

Presumably you are doing:

AA a = new BB();

Which will give 30 if you access a._x since you will access field scoped on class AA.

But if you were to call a.getX() you would call the overridden method and hence get 31 (you will get the field scoped on class BB via the get method).

You will likewise get 31, if you did:

BB b = new BB();

And access b._x;

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you've written

```
    AA a = new BB();
```

since variables are resolved at compile time the _x that you are going to get is the one in class AA. So you get 30 printed. Assuming of course that you do:

```
    System.out.println(a._x);
```

The following should give you 31:

```
    System.out.println(a.getX());
    System.out.println(((BB)a)._x);
```

Answer (score 2):

As said by @drrob, fields are only hidden, not overriden. As polymorphism is behavioral concept. 
And even it makes a difference how do you declare a. To make it clear,
I have added a little code, called from main.

Look at the following scenarios

```
 AA a = new BB ();
 System.out.println( " finally1 = "+a._x);
 System.out.println( " finally2 = "+a.getX ( ));
 BB a1 = new BB ();
 System.out.println( " finally3 = "+a1._x);
 System.out.println( " finally4 = "+a1.getX());
```

Here output for the output shall be as following :

**finally1 = 30**

**finally2 = 31**

**finally3 = 31**

**finally4 = 31**

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism applies only to non-static non-private methods. Variables are resolved in compile-time, so `a._x` will reference the variable declared in `AA` no matter what the actual object is.

Comment: The builder of BB is reffering to the variable in BB or in AA? If I call the getX() function in BB does it returns the value in _x of AA or in BB?

Comment: Any `_x` inside the curly brackets of BB refer to BB's `_x`.  The `getX` method returns AA's `_x`.